# Logout button redirect php

Tags: php, json, logout

i have this logout button in html,

```
 <a href="<?php echo PSF::urlFor('logout');?>" class="link" id="position">Logout</a></li>
```

it goes in the PSF class and searches for logout function, and logs out the user. 
it works fine.

now i am trying to do the same on a popup, via,

```
return json_encode (
    array(
        'errors' => array(
             'Sorry you are already logged in, please Logout from other Devices or click to"<a href="echo PSF::urlFor('logout');" class="link" id="position">Logout</a>"'
        )
    )
);
```

this json is sent to,

```
if (d.errors) {
    $("#load-overlay-elt").isLoading("hide");
    $('#login_wait').button('reset');
    a.empty();
    var msg='';
    $.each(d.errors, function(i, n){
        //a.append(n + '<br/>');
        msg += n + ', ';
    });
    $.auctions.alert(msg);
    a.show();
}
```

the message is printed, but the logout button doesnt seem to work, am i missing something?

Comment: First thing, You can't use `echo` inside array. And second thing, you have to write like this `return json_encode (array('errors' => array( 'Sorry you are already logged in, please Logout from other Devices or click to <a href="'.PSF::urlFor('logout').'" class="link" id="position">Logout</a>')));`

Comment: Okay it is corrected now, but this still searches for a 'logout' page rather than the function,
i mean the html tag finds the function and logs user out, 
this array here looks up for the page rather than the function

Comment: I dont know about your class structure so how can i solved it.

Comment: For that you have to first explain about the PSF class structure and about the function. You can also try echo exit inside function, for confirmation that, it will goes in your function or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the line

```
return json_encode (array('errors' => array( 'Sorry you are already logged in, please Logout from other Devices or click to"<a href="echo PSF::urlFor('logout');" class="link" id="position">Logout</a>"')));
```

to

```
return json_encode (array('errors' => array( 'Sorry you are already logged in, please Logout from other Devices or click to <a href="' . PSF::urlFor('logout') . '" class="link" id="position">Logout</a>"')));
```

as it is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: It is corrected now, but this still searches for a 'logout' page rather than the function, i mean the html tag finds the function and logs user out, this array here looks up for the page rather than the function

Comment: Can you add the output of the `PSF::urlFor('logout')` ?